# Nexus 4 not showing in adb Devices

Tags: android

I have recently updated my drivers and I am unable to connect to my Nexus 4.
The nexus is on 5.1. I'm using Windows 7. My HTC desire can be seen listed in adb devices. 
I have tried re-installing the drivers. The automatic driver installation installs v7.0.0.1. I don't know if this is the latest version as when I point the installer at \extras\google it says that the current driver is up-to-date.

The phone is in debugging mode, and I have also tried different USB ports on the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the phone to connect as camera made it show up on adb devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually change/assign the driver in the Device Manager.

Go to Device Manager - Android Device. 
Select whatever entry you can find here, then choose: 
Update Driver - Browse my computer for driver Software - Let me pick from a List...

Here you should be able to select the proper driver (unticking "Show compatible hardware" should bring some more choices.
If it doesn't work you might want to try using the [Universal adb driver](https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver) (it will be at the "ClockworkMod" manufacturer in the device maanger).

Last but not least, sometimes the issue can be resolved by an adb restart. Just do a `adb kill-server`, then check again for your device using `adb devices`